# Swift: CloudKit subscription firesOnRecordCreation not called as expected

Tags: swift, uikit, cloudkit

This is my register for subscription method

```
public func RegisterForSubscription(completion: @escaping (Result<CKSubscription, Error>) -> Swift.Void) {
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: Film.RecordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnRecordUpdate])

    let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    database.save(subscription) { savedSubscription, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Subscription error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        if let savedSubscription = savedSubscription {
            completion(.success(savedSubscription))
            return
        }
    }        
}
```

Now all i care is `.firesOnRecordCreation` but for debugging purposes, i added all three options.

When I tried adding (save) a new record, it successfully added them to CloudKit. here's the method

```
public func save(film: Film, completion: @escaping (Result<CKRecord, Error>) -> Swift.Void) {
    let filmRecord = film.toRecord()
    
    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [filmRecord], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    operation.completionBlock = {
        completion(.success(filmRecord))
    }
    
    database.add(operation)
}
```

and my `.toRecord()` method:

```
public func toRecord() -> CKRecord {
    let record = self.record ?? CKRecord(recordType: Self.RecordType)
    record[RecordKeys.id.rawValue] = id
    record[RecordKeys.title.rawValue] = title
    record[RecordKeys.filmDescription.rawValue] = filmDescription
    record[RecordKeys.image.rawValue] = image
    record[RecordKeys.director.rawValue] = director
    record[RecordKeys.producer.rawValue] = producer
    record[RecordKeys.releaseDate.rawValue] = releaseDate
    record[RecordKeys.rtScore.rawValue] = rtScore
    record[RecordKeys.imdbLink.rawValue] = imdbLink
    record[RecordKeys.imdbScore.rawValue] = imdbScore
    
    return record
}
```

Everything works. however, I wanted to register for subscription (silent notifications) to detect live changes when user add a new record (film).

The problem is, whenever i add via the method (calling the save method), it is not triggering the `.firesOnRecordCreation` option. However, the other two works. I updated one of the attributes via CloudKit dashboard and deleted them, it is called (on appDelegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification`)

What am i doing wrong? When user added a new film from the method (not VIA dashboard) it should trigger it, but not in this case.

EDIT:

Adding via the dashboard TRIGGERS the susbcription. But NOT when using the method.

Answer (score 1):

The subscription notification will not be received by the device that created, deleted or updated `CKRecord`.

Edit: Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html) about handling subscription notifications.

*You use multiple devices because a notification isn’t sent to the same device that originated the notification*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This makes sense. For now, I just had to disable this feature as of now. Do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: What is your end result?  What do you want to achieve with this notification?